# Replacing patterns using sed

Tags: unix, sed

I want to replace a pattern something like :

```
make_pair(obj1.get<1>(), obj2.get<2>());
```

to:

```
make_pair(get<1>(obj1), get<2>(obj2));
```

Tried with: `sed -i'' -e 's/(\(.*\)./get<1>(\1)/g' file_name`

But getting wrong result.

How to capture tokens before a pattern?

Note that it should also work with `make_pair(obj1[I].get<1>(), obj2[I].get<2>());` string.

Comment: Can the parentheses and brackets contain nested ones? If there are no nested brackets use `sed -i'' -E 's/([[:alnum:]_]*)\.get(<[^><]*>)\(\)/get\2(\1)/g' filename`. See [demo](https://ideone.com/F9spML).

Comment: Thanks, it works if no nested brackets are used. What should be the changes if obj[I].get<1>() is used ?

Comment: So, are there any nested ones? Please specify your requirements.

Comment: Yes, for eg. make_pair(obj1[I].get<1>(), obj2[I].get<2>());

Comment: That  is not nested. `make_pair(obj1.get<1>(txt(more)), obj2.get<2<4>>());` is an example.

Comment: Fine, but your script doesn't works for make_pair(obj1[I].get<1>(), obj2[I].get<2>());   Can you check

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/QDJMz1

Comment: works fine. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i'' -E 's/([[:alnum:]]*(\[[[:alnum:]]*])*)\.get(<[^><]*>)\(\)/get\3(\1)/g'  filename
```

**POSIX ERE pattern details**

- `([[:alnum:]]*(\[[[:alnum:]]*])*)` - Group 1:

  - `[[:alnum:]]*` - 0 or more alphanumeric chars
  - `(\[[[:alnum:]]*])*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `\[` -  a `[` char
    - `[[:alnum:]]*` - 0 or more alphanumeric chars
    - `]` - a `]` char.
- `\.get` - a `.get` substring
- `(<[^><]*>)` - Group 3: a `<`, then 0+ chars other than `<` and `>` and then `>`
- `\(\)` - an empty pair of brackets `()`.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/QDJMz1):

```
s="make_pair(obj1[I].get<1>(), obj2[I].get<2>());"
sed -E 's/([[:alnum:]]*(\[[[:alnum:]]*])*)\.get(<[^><]*>)\(\)/get\3(\1)/g' <<< "$s"
# => make_pair(get<1>(obj1[I]), get<2>(obj2[I]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this please, see if it's what you wanted:

```
$ cat file_name
make_pair(obj1.get<1>(), obj2.get<2>());

$ sed -e 's/\([[:alnum:]]*\)\.\([[:alnum:]<>]*\)()/\2.(\1)/g' file_name
make_pair(get<1>.(obj1), get<2>.(obj2));
```

I removed `-i''` switch, add it back when you see the result is correct for you.